# Django 2 models with ManyToManyField in admin.py

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following in models.py:

```
class Choices(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(_('Full Name'), max_length=50)
    birthdate = models.DateTimeField(_('Birthday'))
    url = models.URLField(_('Website'), blank=True)
    company = models.CharField(_('Company'), max_length=50)
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
            ('M',_('Male')),
            ('F',_('Female')),
            )
    gender = models.CharField(_('Gender'), max_length=200, choices = CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    picture = models.ImageField(_('Picture/Avatar'), upload_to='profile_photo', blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField()
    planguages = models.ManyToManyField(Choices)
```

Now, I want to be able to edit both user profile in admin, as well as option to populate choices users can pick from when creating profile. Being a django newb I am, I managed to make options for editing users profiles only, but didn't manage to populate Choices. Anyhow, I can do it, but I don't know how to have both.

EDITED:
Here's my current admin.py

```
class ChoicesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['description']

class ProfilesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user']

admin.site.register(UserProfile, ProfilesAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `filter_horizontal`

```
class ChoicesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['description']

class ProfilesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user']
    filter_horizontal = ['planguages']

admin.site.register(UserProfile, ProfilesAdmin)
admin.site.register(Choices, ChoicesAdmin)
```

This will allow you to add languages to a user.

Also, you must have the ChoicesAdmin class registered in order to see the green + link to add choices.

Answer (score -1):

Look for inlines in the documentation.

Comment: I did, and I managed to do it, but it's showing me the Choices tied to a user, not Choices I can define.

Comment: @user1164124 - if you have a `ModelAdmin` set up for `Choices`, you'll get a plus icon next to your `planguages` field which would take you to the choices create screen.

Comment: @YujiTomita I tried that, but it says ManyToMany fields are not supported.

Comment: @Milos, nonsense! Register `ChoicesAdmin` and you'll see your green plus.

Comment: @YujiTomita, I can register `admin.site.register(UserProfile, ProfilesAdmin) but then I can't edit user profiles.
`

Comment: @YujiTomita sorry, I can register
`admin.site.register(Choices, ChoicesAdmin)`

Comment: @YujiTomita I just figured I can do admin.site.register as many times I want. Thanks!

Comment: @Milos, ah, no wonder your problem was confusing for us! Glad you figured it out. Enjoy!